# Exec format error with "data" file format

Tags: command-line, file-format, echo

Does anyone knows why it gives format error when i try to run `echo` through `/bin/echo` or `/usr/bin/echo` but works well if i just type `echo` in the command line

```
bash: /usr/bin/echo: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

The output `file /bin/echo`

```
/bin/echo: data
```

What's that `data` file format? Why can't I execute it?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When you just type `echo` in the command line, you are most likely getting your interactive shell's built-in implementation of the the command

Comment: @steeldriver but when i run "which echo" the output is /usr/bin/echo, also can i make the echo script inside bin folder just same as the built in implementation ? so that it doenst give me executable error

Comment: `/bin/echo` should work - it sounds like the file has become corrupted. Perhaps you can fix it by re-installing the `coreutils` package.

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, reinstalling the coreutils package fix the problem

Comment: @steeldriver but there's something that bother my head, you just said `echo` in the command line might be the built in implementation, but why when i run `which echo` the output is `/usr/bin/bash` which is the problematic file, do you know why?

Comment: No I don't know why - I would expect `which echo` to output `/usr/bin/echo` (or `/bin/echo` on a pre-usrmerge system). FYI `which` will only show you external executables - try `type -a echo` instead. See also [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)

Comment: @steeldriver oh i see, thanks for the answer

Comment: lol yeah the output should be /usr/bin/echo, typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is likely something wrong with your `/bin/echo`, as you should get something like this when running `file` on it:

```
/bin/echo: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=714b557112010bbcd04b0e5e6efc1b106166733c, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
```

We can see that `coreutils` is the package that is supposed to provide `/bin/echo` by running:

```
dpkg -S /bin/echo
```

And finally you can check to ensure that none of the files of the package has been modified or corrupted by running:

```
sudo apt install debsums
debsums coreutils
```

If any of the files are corrupted you can re-install them using:

```
sudo apt install coreutils --reinstall
```

Comment: detailed answer, thanks!!